# Load MP3 files on my Nexus

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, mp3

I want to listen to [mp3](/questions/tagged/mp3) files of a lecture while viewing [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf) files (containing the lecture notes).

How do I load the MP3 files onto the Nexus?

(*The MP3 files currently reside on my hard drive.*)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect your device via the USB cable and then drag and drop the files from your PC to your device. You can also transfer the files via a syncing app like Google Drive or Dropbox etc. Use the music player of choice to keep playing the audio files while you use your office viewer / to read the PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options at hand. You can:

- Use an external cloud storage such as [Dropbox](http://db.tt/lFCxLpR). Install the app for your computer and for Android then add files on your computer and watch as they sync on your phone.
- Use Google Play Music. Download the [Music Manager](https://play.google.com/music/listen?u=0#/manager) software and have the software scan your computer for music files. Install the Play Music app on your phone and the music will be available.
- Use a USB cable to directly transfer the files from your computer to your phone.